# How to use ItemWriter to execute mysql LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch

I want to create a `spring-batch` job to batch load csv content (inmemory) into a `mysql` database.

There I have to call a setter on the `Statement` itself.
`st.setLocalInfileInputStream(..)`.

Problem: I tried using `ItemPreparedStatementSetter`, but the `PreparedStatement` inside is only a private proxy that cannot be cast to the statement, getting an exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74 cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement`

So, how can I use an `ItemWriter` to execute the batch insert?

The following does not work:

```
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<String> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    writer.setDataSource(ds);
    writer.setSql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '' into table mytable");

    ItemPreparedStatementSetter<String> ps = new ItemPreparedStatementSetter<String>() {
        @Override
        public void setValues(String csv, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
            //this fails
            ((com.mysql.jdbc.Statement) ps).setLocalInfileInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(csv.getBytes()));
        }
    };

    writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(ps);
    writer.write(Arrays.asList(content));
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thanks

Comment: I did not and dropped spring-batch framework unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Batch, piping a CSV via a prepared statement isn't what a chunk based writer is for.  This is really a task for a `Tasklet` implementation.  From there, you will have more control over the statement you receive, etc.